# Velo - Wix - Counter

Tags: velo

I am building a website that sells tickets and for various reasons I cannot use WixEvents.  I would like to set a counter and have it incremented every time a user hits the select button.

Been trying to do this with collections but just can't seem to find the right reference.

I have also looked at repeaters but I'm struggling with finding the right syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems possible but I wonder what is the purpose of a counter of clicks? It's not like they user actually bought a ticket. I'm asking because I want to make sure I understand the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The click of the button sends them to a hosted payment page so while it certainly wouldn’t be exact it would be close enough to track the number of tickets sold.

Unfortunately the HPP doesn’t return a success/failure so there’s no way to get an exact count from the web page.